# Python Pandas plot. Script does not see a numeric value in text file

Tags: python

I have a script that queries data from a database. It then exports it to a CSV file. The goal is to create a plot with the numeric data in the column. But the script does not see any numerical values in the column specified.

```
import pandas.io.data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime
import pandas.io.data
import psycopg2
import csv
import pandas.io.data

conn = psycopg2.connect("host='172.31.98.161' dbname='servers' user='seeker'")
cur = conn.cursor() #Create the cursor
cur.execute("select hostname, used_ram_raw from server_perf  where                 hostname='localhost.localdomain'")
rows = cur.fetchall()
conn.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['One','Two'])
df.to_csv("file.csv")
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)    
df[['Two']].plot()
plt.show()
```

The above script produces the following file called "file.csv"

```
,One,Two
0,localhost.localdomain,1521819648.00
1,localhost.localdomain,1632538624.00
2,localhost.localdomain,1633038336.00
3,localhost.localdomain,1632264192.00
```

The error produced is whn trying to plot is:

```
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Just for testing I did a

```
  print df[['Two']]
```

and it printed the following

```
             Two
0  1521819648.00
1  1632538624.00
2  1633038336.00
3  1632264192.00
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very likely that if you would type

```
df.Two.dtype
```

It would output that its type is a string (It would say it's `Object` or something like that).

This is easily remedied. If you need to do something numeric with it, use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df.Two.astype(float)
```

In fact, you can just reassign it back to itself:

```
df.Two = df.Two.astype(float)
```

Comment: Thank you Ami !!! It worked. Here is the corrected code.


    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['One','Two'])
    df.to_csv("file.csv")

    print df[['Two']]

    print df.Two.dtype

    df.Two = df.Two.astype(float)

    df[['Two']].plot()
    plt.show()

Comment: I had to do this for the `x-axis` and `y-axis`.